# Store strings + description in filesystem

Tags: algorithm, csv, file-storage

I have more than 100million Strings that I want to store on a filesystem. Together with the string (~255Chars utf8) there will be two dates and some integer values that define its properties.

I could put them in a CSV file but it would be huge. I could put several smaller CSV files in subdirectories to make it faster or I could simply create a file for each string and store them in a directory tree.

How do I know which solution is faster and easier to mantain/develop? I don't even know how sparse my strings are; maybe I have 50 millions that starts with the same characters, thus making the tree not so balanced.

Right now I think I might make a directory structure with the first 5 characters and then put csv files in each directory. Eg. the string "I don't know what I'm doing" -> "Idontknowwhatimdoing" goes into

> /i/d/o/n/t/list.csv

Any better idea? I can't use a Db.I'm using java to store and php to read the filesystem, if that makes any difference.

Comment: Maybe have a look at Redis - depending what you want to **do** with your strings - it is fast and scalable.

Comment: that's the kind of thing databases were developed for...take a look at sqlite for example, if you want something that is easy to access.

Comment: Do not use your homebrew solution. With this amount of data an existing database solution is the way to go.

Comment: @SteffenWinkler I"m testing it on shared hosting, so I can't use fancy stuff as DBs or else :-)

Comment: I can't imagine you will be allowed to store 100 million files on shared hosting if you aren't permitted to install a database.

Comment: 100 million strings, if average 10 characters (surely a k-v pair would be much greater in size), we are talking of more than 1 gB data. Are you sure you want to store in a file?

Comment: What do you plan to actually do with the strings? That will determine the access patterns and what you need to optimise for.

Comment: @vish4071 a mysqldump on my localhost shows 21Gb of data. I'm sure some of it is useless. The strings alone on a txt file were 8Gb. The problem of hosting 21Gb of db isn't the size, but the cpu consumption, so 8-10gb on a filesystem shoudn't be an issue.

Comment: @MarkSetchell  a php script that return a json block with info about that string.

Comment: So you search for a string by its time?

Comment: @MarkSetchell I search the string itself and return the valued stored with it. e.g. "google.com" returns "1", "2015-01-15" where 1 means "site" and the date is the update date. So I have to store "google.com,1,2015-01-15"

Comment: @mobinoob take a deeper look at sqlite, if you are allowed to execute .net code and create files, sqlite will be fine. From their webpage `SQLite is a software library that implements a self-contained, serverless, zero-configuration, transactional SQL database engine`

Comment: I can pretty much guarantee that a database solution will consume much less CPU time than will searching sequential files.

Answer (score 1):

- A database with indexing would be much more optimal.
- The following has the caveat of a fixed record size.

If your strings are ASCII where you only need one byte to define each character (vs UTF8 where some characters may encode to 4 bytes) then you can just use  flat file(s) with a fixed size for each record. If you're strings really do need to be UTF8 then choose a fixed size encoding instead of a variable size encoding or just find the largest string and use that as your fixed size.

**256 bytes (string) + 8 byte (date) + 8 byte (date) + 8 byte (integer) + 8 byte (integer) = 288 bytes per record**

**100million (entries) * 288 bytes (record size) = 28.8 GB**

Accessing a giant file like that means you'll have to use *memory mapped files* where the OS takes care of only putting the part of the file you are currently accessing into memory.

If your strings weren't sorted you'll have to do that, some merge sort varient would probably be useful where you can completely sort chunks of the 100 millions strings (maybe partitions of 1million) then merge those 100 sorted partitions together to get the final sorted list.

How to search for a string would be a *binary search* **log N**, for 100million records that would be ~27 IO reads.

Comment: Thanks but I can't use it. Yet.sqllite maybe.

Comment: @mobinoob - maybe you didn't read my whole answer (bad formatting on my part). I outlined a completely SQL-free method using only flat files.

Comment: totally my fault sorry. :(